# Sonarqube doesn't start from Docker

Tags: scala, docker, sonarqube

I'm trying to run Sonarqube from Docker with `sonar.sh start`.

When I look over the logs `grep -i Exception *`  I see this:

```
ce.log:org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException:
ce.log:### Error querying database.  Cause: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Connection is broken: "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused): localhost:9092" [90067-176]
ce.log:### Cause: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Connection is broken: "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused): localhost:9092" [90067-176]
ce.log: at org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:26)
ce.log:Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Connection is broken: "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused): localhost:9092" [90067-176]
ce.log: at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:344)
ce.log: at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:167)
ce.log:Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
web.log:2017.02.11 14:30:00 ERROR web[][o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/]] Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.sonar.server.platform.web.PlatformServletContextListener
web.log:java.lang.IllegalStateException: Metric [scoverage] is already defined by the repository [com.buransky.plugins.scoverage.measure.ScalaMetrics@63c004ba]
web.log:java.lang.IllegalStateException: Webapp did not start
```

Some of these exceptions refer to the database, but I don't think there should be any issue with that since I haven't modified the embedded database.

I think this could be the most relevant issue, since I added a Scala plugin to Sonarqube:

```
web.log:java.lang.IllegalStateException: Metric [scoverage] is already defined by the repository [com.buransky.plugins.scoverage.measure.ScalaMetrics@63c004ba]
```

Any idea what could be causing Sonarqube to fail in Docker?

Comment: Which image are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I had the `sonar-scala` plugin in `sonarqube/extensions/` and `sonarqube/extensions/plugins`.

After I removed it from `sonarqube/extensions/`, it started working. Not sure why though.

Comment: The plug you mention is very old. SonarQube changes quite often the main program so after several SonarQube updates the plugin will not work anymore. It is always important to mention the SonarQube and plugin versions in your questions.